# Homology of inverse limits over inverse systems more complicated than towers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Most textbooks discussions of homology of inverse limits of chain complexes consider only “towers,” i.e. inverse systems indexed by the natural numbers. I’d like to find a reference that explains what happens more generally, for example for more arbitrary inverse systems.

In the particular application I have in mind, the inverse system is indexed by all triangulations of a PL space that are compatible with the PL structure, and the maps of the inverse systems are essentially the Hom duals of the chain maps induced by subdivisions of the triangulations. Further, there are some other nice things in my setting: all of the chain complexes are bounded-below (with cohomological indexing) chain complexes of projective modules over a Dedekind domain, and each map in the inverse system is a surjective chain homotopy equivalence. So it seems somewhat reasonable to me that if the chain complexes are labeled $C_\alpha$ then the maps $H^*(\varprojlim C_\alpha)\to H^*(C_\alpha)$ is an isomorphism for any $\alpha$, but I haven’t been able to find anything in the literature to support this.

Thanks!

Comment: To be complete, one should mention: Eilenberg & Steenrod, *Foundations of Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: If your diagram were Reedy fibrant, then it would be easy to deduce what you want. If you were dealing with towers, your surjection condition would suffice, but since you're not, maybe you can have a look at the technical statement and see whether Reedy fibrancy holds. See the notion of Reedy fibration in Theorem 5.1.3 of Hovey's Model Categories book.